# How to exit Visual Studio Code - Debug Console REPL?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Does the ">" arrowhead at bottom in attached picture for the vscode Debug Console REPL indicate I am in the middle of a debug session (application is crashing). If so, how do I exit this state.

[image: Debug Console REPL]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, just figured it out by setting up a fresh installation of Visual Studio Code on a separate computer. As I suspected, the arrowhead ">" DOES NOT mean that I am presently in Debug mode.

You will even see ">" before you start ANY debug session.